# netbeans java println ternary variable unrecognized

Tags: java, netbeans, ternary

Hey I have an error in my java code for some reason that's driving me crazy because I can't figure it out. Here's my code:

```
                package com.java24hours;
                class ternary {
                int skilllevel = 5;
                int numberOfEnemies = (skilllevel > 5) ? 20 : 10;
   error here-> System.out.println(numberOfEnemies);
                }
```

the error code suggestion says to create class numberOfEnemies in package com.java24hours

the actual error code reads

1.cannot find symbol

2.Symbol: class out

3.location: class System

4.identifier expected

Comment: place the `println` statement in a method

Comment: Have you tried _formatting_ your code?

Answer (score 0):

The statement must be inside a block of code, so if you just want to print that you might add it to the constructor of the class.